# Correcting rough edges

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv, image-processing

There's an image which has been extracted from another image clicked from a certain height(approx. 130ft). Now when this smaller image is extracted it contains an object, which actually has very regular and a smooth shape, has got very rough edges. Now I want to detect the no. of corners, the object has(without using contours). But due to these rough edges the no. of corners detected increases enormously.

Here are the sample images:
[image: Rectangle]
[image: Semi-Circle]

How can I make the edges straight?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is a simple edge smoothening algorithm. I implemented one for you. It doesn't save the colorful sign inside the outer shape though - if that's important too - since you haven't mentioned that in the question - you'll have to figure that part on your own. The result:

[image]

I've implemented track bars so you can play with the values of smoothening however it suits you. Press "c" to confirm the values you have chosen.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np


def empty_function(*arg):
    pass


def SmootherEdgesTrackbar(img, win_name):
    trackbar_name = win_name + "Trackbar"

    cv2.namedWindow(win_name, cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
    cv2.resizeWindow(win_name, 1000, 500)
    cv2.createTrackbar("first_blur", win_name, 3, 255, empty_function)
    cv2.createTrackbar("second_blur", win_name, 3, 255, empty_function)
    cv2.createTrackbar("threshold", win_name, 0, 255, empty_function)

    while True:
        first_blur_pos = cv2.getTrackbarPos("first_blur", win_name)
        second_blur_pos = cv2.getTrackbarPos("second_blur", win_name)
        thresh_pos = cv2.getTrackbarPos("threshold", win_name)
        if first_blur_pos < 3:
            first_blur_pos = 3
        if second_blur_pos < 3:
            second_blur_pos = 3
        img_res = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        img_res = smoother_edges(img_res, (first_blur_pos * 2 + 1, first_blur_pos * 2 + 1),
                                 (second_blur_pos * 2 + 1, second_blur_pos * 2 + 1))
        _, img_res = cv2.threshold(img_res, thresh_pos, 255, 0)
        cv2.imshow(win_name, img_res)

        key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
        if key == ord("c"):
            break

    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    return img_res


def unsharp_mask(img, blur_size, imgWeight, gaussianWeight):
    gaussian = cv2.GaussianBlur(img, blur_size, 0)
    return cv2.addWeighted(img, imgWeight, gaussian, gaussianWeight, 0)


def smoother_edges(img, first_blur_size, second_blur_size=(5, 5),
                   imgWeight=1.5, gaussianWeight=-0.5):
    # blur the image before unsharp masking
    img = cv2.GaussianBlur(img, first_blur_size, 0)
    # perform unsharp masking
    return unsharp_mask(img, second_blur_size, imgWeight, gaussianWeight)


# read the image
img = cv2.imread("sample.jpg")
# smoothen edges
img = SmootherEdgesTrackbar(img, "Smoother Edges Trackbar")
# show and save image
cv2.imshow("img", img)
cv2.imwrite("result.png", img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

**EDIT:**
After you figure out what values suit you, just delete the track bar function and perform the steps with fixed values. The algorithm goes like this:

```
convert to gray
blur
unsharp mask
threshold
```

2 middle steps are combined in smoother_edges() function.

Comment: The output posted by you is really good. So lemme tell you what I was able to understand your program is doing. First, it asks the user to manually set the thresholding and blur values and then it passes these values to other functions which apply uses these values to apply thresholding and blur to the image implicitly. Also, I'm only getting a small white window after setting the threshold and blur. By the way thanks.

Comment: . And also I wanted the one which doesn't involves any manual work

Comment: After you figure out what values suit you, just delete the track bar function and perform the steps with fixed values. The algorithm goes like this:
convert to gray, blur, unsharp mask, threshold. 2 middle steps are combined in smoother_edges() function.